# Combine two partitions belonging to one phsyical drive?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

when I first setup my Ubuntu Server, I had 1 x 3TB drive. Since I couldn't partition/format it into a 3TB ext4, I partitioned it into 2 x 1.5TB ext4.

- partition1 = 1.5TB
- partition2 = 1.5TB

Now I read that I could have changed from MBR to GPT but too late now, I already have data on partition1.

My question now is, what's the best way to combine it without having to repartition and reformat?

Will I be able to use LVM to combine them into 1 big volume?

Answer (score 1):

LVM won't work as you would have to re-format.

There are a lot of questions here, but basically your best best is

Use parted to migrate your MBR to GPT. Basically uss "parted p" to get the current MBR layout and then make the GTP layout match EXCATLY. This "should not" experience data loss.

Fix your boot issues by reinstalling grub/fixing references (assuming it yours boot volume).

Next delete Partition 2

Resize partition 1

Then grow your ext4 file system to the full size of the new larger partition.

IMPORTANT:

You should not experience data loss, but you very well could. Make backups, and check your file system for errors before doing this.

Comment: I just did this last night my self, It worked perfectly fine, with the exception that I had to purge and reinstall grub because I was going from a MBR version (bios) to a EFI version (pure efi). This was handled quite well with [Boot Repair](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/boot-repair-simple-tool-to-repair-frequent-boot-problems.html)